# How to refer the web file for RESTlet script in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

I have created two RESTlet file.

First one uploaded from computer . Script id - 1, Deployment id - 1
Second one uploaded from web . Script id - 2, Deployment id - 1

The RESTlet which was uploaded from computer, can call by token details and can get Netsuite details.

But i could not call and access from Script id -2 and Deployment id-1.

I got reference error, when i call the RESTlet script uploaded from web.
This is the link of my file
http://support.gunify.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/gu_method.js

Error

```
Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [code] => REFERENCE_ERROR
            [message] => ReferenceError: "gu_method" is not defined. (null$lib#4).
        )

)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code snippet of restlet with errors?

Comment: i have added now Prasun

Comment: Are you able to see the same file in file cabinet and also do you see the file extension as js?

Comment: Yes i can see that file in file cabinet. Name - gu_method, Size -0 KB, Last Modified - 01/20/2016 10:28 am, Type - JavaScript File

Comment: There isn't any content in the file that is why it did not went through.  Try uploading through a different browser.

Comment: If i upload , it will work fine. I want to refer from the web link only

Comment: I meant upload from Web link itself but a different browser

Comment: Still not working prasun

Comment: the error isn't in RESTlet , the error is in upload mechanism, you should file a case with NetSuite ion why file is being uploaded as zero size