# How to change the RESTlet script file or modify code using RESTlet in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

RESTlet file has been uploaded for multiple users. There are so many changes made frequently. Uploading the script file again for multiple users is not possible.

Ex: I am getting contacts of the users using RESTlet file. Some times i got an error. i could understand and clear the error. But i added code to solve the error.

So i have to again upload new or modify the old script for every user whoever using my script file and got an error.

I already tried to refer the script in web and i posted the issue which i faced in [How to refer the web file for RESTlet script in Netsuite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947515/how-to-refer-the-web-file-for-restlet-script-in-netsuite)

But still no solution for my error.

So i am trying to do that user have to upload two scripts. 
Main Script & Sub script.

Ex : i want to update the code of Main script (RESTlet) by calling another Sub script

or add/update the Main script code by calling Main script itself.

so i want to change the file or modify the code of RESTlet Script file using another RESTlet file or same RESTlet file itself.

Or any other solution..?

Comment: Can you give more details.

Comment: i have added some more details Frederick.